# Error reading shapefiles using geopandas in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I have a line shapefile file and I'm using the following code to read in it.

```
import geopandas as gpd
line = gpd.read_file(r"./line_UTM16.shp")
```

GeoDataframe 'line' exist though with the following errors:

```
INFO     model.py:56  Reading line shapefile.
WARNING  collection.py:145 GDAL data files not located, GDAL_DATA not set
WARNING  collection.py:145 PROJ data files not located, PROJ_LIB not set
DEBUG    collection.py:203 Got coordinate system
DEBUG    collection.py:247 Index: 0
DEBUG    collection.py:210 Got coordinate system
DEBUG    collection.py:404 Flushed buffer
DEBUG    collection.py:406 Stopped session
```

I'm using Python 3.6, I checked my package version:

```
geopandas    0.3.0   
fiona        1.7.10  
gdal         2.2.3   
proj4        4.9.3
```

How can I solve it, I think it is a data installation problem? The code runs fine for many days, and suddenly it is reporting the errors. 
Thanks!

**UPDATE:** 
I did some research and it says that gdal only works with Python3.5, so I created a separate environment with Python3.5 and all the packages. The problem still exists!  GDAL_DATA not set and PROJ_LIB not set. Not sure if this is a software bug?

Comment: How does your .shp look like? Do you got the same problem when reading other .shp? And what do you really want?

Comment: @kitman0804 My shapefile is a list of multistrings and linestrings. I have the same problem reading other .shp. What I want is read in the shapefile, select by attributes, create buffer, and then join. I have the following code ready, just stucked with the first step: read files.

Comment: But the file was read in correctly? (you say "GeoDataframe 'line' exist") If so, I don't think you need to worry about this logging output. However, geopandas should not show it, but I thought this was fixed for geopandas 0.3.0 (see https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/468 and https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/496)

Comment: In any case, GDAL certainly works in python 3.6 as well. How did you install geopandas, fiona, gdal?

Comment: @joris Yes, file read in correctly, just with the logging warnings. Not sure if it will affect my later on calculations. I installed geopandas with severl different ways: conda install, conda-forge and pip. All three have the same warnings. I searched online and looks like it was a bug in geopandas and was fixed last year. Not sure why I encounter this.